# Expectation value of the product of spin and momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Let's say we want the expectation value of $\langle S\cdot L\rangle$.
How can one multiply a $3\times 3$ matrix (angular momentum) and $2\times2$ matrix (each $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$) ?

What is the physical meaning of this expectation value?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is not the "usual" multiplication. What you have there is a tensor product of the two operators. The total Hilbert space of the state vectors is a tensor product of two spaces and each operator acts in its own subspace.
For example, you can have a state
$$|\Psi\rangle = |nlm_l\rangle \otimes |sm_s\rangle$$
and $LS= L_x S_x+L_y S_y +L_z S_z$. Then
$$L_xS_x |\Psi\rangle=L_x S_x|nlm_l\rangle \otimes |sm_s\rangle=( L_x|n_lm_l\rangle) \otimes (S_x|s m_s\rangle)$$
and so on for the other two components.